# sbt assembly task runs slowly after adding some dependencies

Tags: scala, deployment, sbt, apache-spark, sbt-assembly

I'm kind of new to deployment in scala and I configured the `sbt-assembly` plugin, all worked well.

Some days ago I added hadoop, spark and some other dependencies, then the `assembly` task become extremely slow (8 to 10 minutes) and before that, it was < 30s. **Most of the time is used for generating the assembly-jar (it takes several seconds for the jar to grow 1MB in size).**

I observed that there's a lot of merge conflicts, which are resolved by `first` strategy. Does this affects the speed of assembly?

I've played with the -Xmx option for sbt (add -Xmx4096m) but it doesn't help.

I'm using `sbt` 12.4 and `sbt-assembly`. Any suggestions or pointers for optimize this task?

Comment: Have you read the [Readme](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly). It specifically suggests that you might change the `cacheUnzip` and `cacheOutput` settings. I would give it a try.

Comment: @0__ I've read it but it seems that all optimization options are on by default

Comment: Yes, but they are _options_. It might be worth trying to switch each of the caching options _off_ to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I've tried combinations with both options but it doesn't seem to fix the problem. However sometimes if I do a clean first, assembly will be very fast, but this behavior is not consistent.

Comment: Then perhaps best is to file an issue on the project page and hope for feedback from the author...

Comment: The issue reporting guideline of sbt-assembly says that support questions should be asked on StackOverflow, so OP came to the right place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So [0__](https://stackoverflow.com/users/515054/0)'s comment is right on:

> Have you read the [Readme](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly). It specifically suggests that you might change the `cacheUnzip` and `cacheOutput` settings. I would give it a try.

`cacheUnzip` is an optimization feature, but `cacheOutput` isn't. The purpose of `cacheOutput` is so that you get the identical jar when your source has not changed. For some people, it's important to that output jars don't change unnecessarily. The caveat is that it's checking the SHA-1 hash of all *.class files. So the readme says:

> If there are a large number of class files, this could take a long time

From what I can tell, unzipping and application of merge strategy together takes around a minute or two, but the checking of the SHA-1 seems to take forever. Here's `assembly.sbt` that turns off the output cache:

```
import AssemblyKeys._ // put this at the top of the file

assemblySettings

mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>  {
    case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*)         => MergeStrategy.first
    case PathList("org", "apache", "commons", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first // commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar vs commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
    case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", "minlog", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first // kryo-2.21.jar vs minlog-1.2.jar
    case "about.html"                                  => MergeStrategy.rename
    case x => old(x)
  }
}

assemblyCacheOutput in assembly := false
```

The assembly finished in 58 seconds after cleaning, and the second run without cleaning took 15 seconds. Although some of the runs took 200+ secs too.

Looking at the source, I probably could optimize `cacheOutput`, but for now, turning it off should make assembly much faster.

**Edit**:

I've added [#96 Performance degradation when adding library dependencies](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/issues/96) based on this question, and added some fixes in [sbt-assembly 0.10.1](http://notes.implicit.ly/post/65751699253/sbt-assembly-0-10-1) for sbt 0.13.

> sbt-assembly 0.10.1 avoids content hashing of the unzipped items of the dependent library jars. It also skips jar caching done by sbt, since sbt-assembly is already caching the output.
>
> The changes make assembly task run more consistently. Using deps-heavy spark as sample project, assembly task was run 15 times after a small source change. sbt-assembly 0.10.0 took 19+/-157 seconds (mostly within 20 secs, but going 150+ secs 26% of the runs). On the other hand, sbt-assembly 0.10.1 took 16+/-1 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

For each added library dependency, the assembly process has to unpack all of the archives, then repack the contents into a fat jar.

The process is I/O heavy, and if you have an anti-virus, it is going to scan each file.

What worked for me was adding the project's directory as an **excluded** folder in the **anti-virus settings** which changed the assembly time from 60 to 12 seconds.

In addition, if you run the assembly command with the ~ in the front as:

```
sbt ~assembly
```

Then sbt will wait for source changes in the project, then do the packaging without reloading the JVM.

This reduced the assembly time from 12s to 8s (small project with two library dependencies).

Comment: As @nillas mentions disabling the anti virus scan on your project directory made the big improvement on assembly times. Be aware that some anti virus tools (Sophos) require a restart for the change to be picked up it would appear.